# how to create several ahref link in unity moodel pop-up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Is it possible to create ahref link in a pop up window or is it possible to support html tag ahref in a popup window

What I want to achieve is when user clicks on a game object a model popup will be displayed and on that model pop story title and story link will be displayed as a list and when user clicks on any of the link, it must open the url in a browser window.

I tried this modal but ahref not working in this popup

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;

    // example:
    // HFTDialog.MessageBox("error", "Sorry but you're S.O.L", () => { Application.Quit() });

    public class HFTDialog : MonoBehaviour {

        Rect m_windowRect;
        Action m_action;
        string m_title;
        string m_msg;

        static public void MessageBox(string title, string msg, Action action)
        {
            GameObject go = new GameObject("HFTDialog");
            HFTDialog dlg = go.AddComponent<HFTDialog>();
            dlg.Init(title, msg, action);
        }


        static public void CloseMessageBox(GameObject go)
        {
           Destroy(go.gameObject);
        }

        void Init(string title, string msg, Action action)
        {
            m_title = title;
            m_msg = msg;
            m_action = action;
        }

        void OnGUI()
        {
            const int maxWidth = 640;
            const int maxHeight = 480;

            int width = Mathf.Min(maxWidth, Screen.width - 20);
            int height = Mathf.Min(maxHeight, Screen.height - 20);
            m_windowRect = new Rect(
                (Screen.width - width) / 2,
                (Screen.height - height) / 2,
                width,
                height);

            m_windowRect = GUI.Window(0, m_windowRect, WindowFunc, m_title);
        }

        void WindowFunc(int windowID)
        {
            const int border = 10;
            const int width = 50;
            const int height = 25;
            const int spacing = 10;

            Rect l = new Rect(
                border,
                border + spacing,
                m_windowRect.width - border * 2,
                m_windowRect.height - border * 2 - height - spacing);
            GUI.Label(l, m_msg);

            Rect b = new Rect(
                m_windowRect.width - width - border,
                m_windowRect.height - height - border,
                width,
                height);

            if (GUI.Button(b, "close"))
            {
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
                m_action();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) (a Javascript derivative created for Unity) and not C#?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. This also has nothing to do with [tag:unity-container]